# Dependency inversion: python

Tags: python, dependency-injection, abstract-class

i have an interface called EmailService:

```
from zope.interface import Interface
from src.utils.Email import Email

"""
@author: 
"""
class EmailService(Interface):

    def sendMail(self, mail):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

and a class EmailServiceImpl which represents the implementation of this interface:

```
from zope.interface import implementer
from src.services.EmailService import EmailService
from lbc.log_conf import  LoggerManager
"""
@author: 
"""
@implementer(EmailService)
class EmailServiceImpl():

        def __init__(self):
            logger = LoggerManager.__call__().get_logger()
            logger.info("Email Service Implementation")

        def sendMail(self, mail):
            print("send mail")
```

I wanna my class main depend upon abstractions

```
class main():

    def __init__(self):
        self.service = EmailService

    def sendMail(self):
        self.mail = Email("test","test","test","test")
        self.service.sendMail(self,self.mail)
```

but when i try to inject my inteface, i have this error:

> AttributeError: 'InterfaceClass' object has no attribute 'sendMail'

Comment: I don't know about Zope and dependency injection, but do you need an instance of `EmailServiceImpl`?

Comment: @PeterWood i used the librairy Zope.interface in order to define EmailService as an interface and which EmailServiceImpl is its implementation. In my exemple i dont want an instance of EmailServiceImpl. I dont want my class main  depend on details.(EmailServiceImpl). i would apply the Dependency Inversion Principle which the Details should depend upon abstractions(here in my exemple EmailService).

Comment: Can you show what you mean by “try to inject”?

Comment: @PeterWood i want wire the depedency EmailService  into the class main and use its methodes which are implemented in the class EmailServiceImpl

Comment: You said it doesn’t work when you try to inject the dependency. How are you doing that? Edit the question so we don’t have to chat.

Comment: @PeterWood yes the code in the main class doesn't work. cauz when i call the Interface EmailService it doesn't knows its methodes despite i defines it in the interface and implements it in the class EmailServiceImpl

Comment: Like I said, edit the question. You're not describing **how** you perform the injection, or why you expect `service` to be anything other than `EmailService`. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve]. If your question isn't clear it will be closed.